# setting json html on react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a some as an array in the JSON format. I need to render that content. How can I convert the JSON to normal HTML elements without using any package or setDangerous method?

```
let data = [
    "John Doe Interests are",
    "<ul>\n <li>\n a) Football </li>\n  <li>b) Hockey</li>\n</ul>",
    "Good"
]
```

It should look like this:

```css
ul {
 list-style: none
}
```

```html
John Doe Interests are
<ul>
  <li>Football</li>
  <li>Hockey</li>
</ul>
Good
```

Comment: `without using [...] setDangerous method.` why? (also, JSON is irrelevant here; what you have is an array)

Comment: But i get this data as json its a json file, so how can i convert this to html without quotes and breaklines

Comment: You can convert it to a single string with `data.join('')`

Comment: but if i do data.join(" ") it won't render as a html element isn't, instead ul , li will be printed as a string isn't

Comment: Once the JSON text is parsed into an array, it doesn't matter that it used to be JSON. It's now an array of strings which contain linebreaks (the quotes are delimiters and not part of the strings). So your issue is "how do I insert a bunch of strings into my React component", and the way to do that is dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: @ChrisG  thanks for correctly asking the question so before using dangerouslySetInnerHTML do i need to purify it ? because i have seen in docs that its not safe

Comment: What's the origin of the data you're inserting? Is it user-generated?

Comment: Nope its a localisation

Comment: Ok, so no need to sanitize it then, I guess?

Comment: Do i require a html parser package also ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233424/discussion-between-dev-and-chris-g).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using these packages. Don't need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` anymore.

- [dompurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) - To sanitize HTML
- [React HTML Parser](https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser) - Converting HTML strings into React components.

**data.json**

```json
[
  "John Doe Interests are",
  "<ul>\n <li>\n a) Football </li>\n  <li>b) Hockey</li>\n</ul>",
  "Good"
]
```

**App.js**

```js
import DOMPurify from "dompurify";
import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";
import data from "./data.json";

function App() {
  return (
    <>{data.map((content) => ReactHtmlParser(DOMPurify.sanitize(content)))}</>
  );
}

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/json-to-react-f0rgj?file=/src/App.js

Let me know if you need further support.